# A school class of 20 students is to pose with a team for the Mathematics Olympics. The team can consist of any number of (1,2,3, ..., 20)

Tags: combinatorics

I can calculate this by

$$20+\left(\begin{array}{c}{20} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}{20} \\ {3}\end{array}\right)+\ldots+\left(\begin{array}{l}{20} \\ {20}\end{array}\right)$$

But this does not correspond to any of the answers (it's a multiple choice).

Q1: Are there a compact way to calculate this via some theorem?

Q2: This is a combination and not a permutation, am I right?

Comment: Try thinking about it this way: you're choosing a subset of the set {1,2,...,20}. How many subsets of {1,2,...,20} are there? Do you remember what a power set is? Try representing subsets of {1,2,...,20} as binary strings of length 20.

Comment: AH!!!! :) $$|P(A)|=2^{|A|}$$ 
Thanks

Comment: I don't see a full problem statement here.  What it is that you're trying to calculate?

Comment: @jwodder The cardinality of the power set minus one. I solved the problem yesterday. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically the number of elements in the power set of a set of $20$ elements excluding the empty set. Since each element in the $20$-element set can either be in the power set or not, there are $2^{20}$ such elements, and excluding the empty set gives a total of $2^{20}-1.$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{20}{20\choose i}=2^{20}-1$$Since each combination counts the number of subsets of a given size of a set of cardinality $20$.

Answer (score 3):

You want to count the number of non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,20\}$. As you said, one way to calculate this sum would be $$\sum_{i=1}^{20}\binom{20}{i}.$$ However, there's another way. For each student, you can either choose them, or not. These choices are all independent, giving $2^{20}$ possible teams, minus $1$ since the empty team is not allowed. Generalizing this approach, we can in fact arrive at the more general equation $$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}=2^n,$$ which is proved in an analogous manner.